# Retrieve data from firebase to "select" on Cordova (Ionic framework) Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Iam new using angularjs & firebase with ionic framework,

I want to fill a "dropdown" with information coming from firebase.

**Firebase :**

```
|--0
   |--day
   |--pred
       |--0
          |--name
          |--crit
       |--1
          |--name
          |--crit
|--1
   |--day
   |--pred
       |--0
          |--name
          |--crit
       |--1
          |--name
          |--crit
.......etc.....
```

**Js :**

```
// stored data coming from firebase (Controller)
$scope.data = $firebaseArray(fb);
```

**Html :**

```
 <select ng-model="myColor" ng-options="d.day for d in data"></select><br> //This one is working 

<select ng-model="myColor2" ng-options="d.pred.name for d in data"></select><br> // This one is NOT WORKING
```

The main problem is how to loop information of all data ignoring "THE UNIQUE ID 0, 1" given by firebase for an array?

Maybe my firebase structure is not correct. Any advice will be helpful. Thank you